# ufw blocks ssh even if it is allowed

Tags: networking, ssh, firewall, ufw

I have a fresh ubuntu installation. I try to install ufw and just allow ssh but immediately after enabling ufw I lose my ssh connection. I execute below commands after setting up the initial ssh connection.

```
apt-get update
apt-get install ufw

ufw reset
ufw default deny incoming
ufw default allow outgoing
ufw allow ssh
ufw allow 22/tcp
ufw enable
```

Then I lose my ssh connection and cannot connect to my server again until I reboot it from the cloud console. I tried with 14.04 and 16.04 but both behave same. I am sure ufw is not installed on the machine at the beginning.

Comment: isn't `ufw allow ssh` and `ufw allow 22/tcp` twice the same thing ?

Comment: Yep, just to make sure. I tried them separately as well.

Comment: I'm seeing the same issue on a fresh server 20.04.3 LTS install.  The moment I enable `ufw`, all remote ssh is blocked even though `sudo ufw status numbered` shows it is allowed.